bigquery schema deployment using liquibase failing with 400 Bad Request
getting below error when trying to deploy bigquery schema with Liquibase.
SEVERE [liquibase.integration] [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [1:35] [Failed SQL: (100032) CREATE TABLE projectId.databasename.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID STRING(255), AUTHOR STRING(255), FILENAME STRING(255), DATEEXECUTED datetime, ORDEREXECUTED INT, EXECTYPE STRING(10), MD5SUM STRING(35), DESCRIPTION STRING(255), COMMENTS STRING(255), TAG STRING(255), LIQUIBASE STRING(20), CONTEXTS STRING(255), LABELS STRING(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID STRING(10))]

I have not made any changes to databasechangelog table or the databasechangeloglock table liquibase is executing its internal command.
in the properties i m using following url string :
url: jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=projectId;DefaultDataset=projectId.databasename;OAuthType=3;

and running the below liquibase command . This i am executing in the kubernetes cluster where i have provided the required role to the service account
liquibase update --changelog-file=/changelog/changeSetFile.sql --url=jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=projectId;DefaultDataset=projectId.databasename;OAuthType=3; --log-level=INFO

I have also tried setting as following, but still not working:
DefaultDataset=databasename

I'd be tempted to see if there are any messages/errors logged into the Google Cloud logging logs.  Another thought ... are there any special characters in your actual project name or dataset name?

yes.. as special characters have hyphens '-' in the projectID and underscores '_' in the dataset name

Shubham is correct. Right now Liquibase Bigquery extension is not quoting the project/schema/table names when running queries. And according to Bigquery documentation , to use unquoted identifiers you have to follow those rules:

Must begin with a letter or an underscore (_) character.
Subsequent characters can be letters, numbers, or underscores (_).

If I'm right project id is generated by Bigquery, so you would need to recreate it to get rid of any special character different from _ until liquibase releases a version that quotes those values.
